# Taylor expansion of an operator product

Tags: maple

I've tracked down this code: http://www.yorku.ca/marko/ComPhys/NoncomProduct/NoncomProduct.html .  However, I suspect it's ancient.  It dates, apparently, from 2005.  It requires an army of definemore's to work, and requires this code:

```
Ut:=subs((A+B)^2=(A+B)&*(A+B),(A+B)^3=(A+B)&*(A+B)&*(A+B),(A+B)^4=(A+B)&*(A+B)&*(A+B)&*(A+B),Ut);
```

to get the non-commuting operators to evaluate properly.  clearly, this gets worse as you go to higher order.  I'm quite convinced there should be something that works to arbitrary order, though perhaps not for the maple versions this code was writen for.

So, the question: I'm currently using maple 13.  Is there a better way to do this in maple 13, or in the latest versions of maple?  This might be a good reason to invest in a newer version.

thanks..

Edit:  Thank's for the response @acer; I wasn't all that explicit about this, but If there is a much better way to implement this algorithm in the newest versions of maple, please say so.  I might actually invest in a new version..  thank's!

Comment: The `Physics` package of modern Maple (current release is `17`) has support for noncommutative variables and functions, and much else besides. See http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=Physics for the online help. I would not be surprised if the whole sheet you cited couldn't be done cleanly and tersely. But ask on www.mapleprimes.com because the Maplesoft developer of the Maple Physics package participates on the forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't looked at those `definemore` definitions, but as far as the initial substitutions of powers go you could even in Maple 13 try something like either of these (instead of that hard-coded sequence of substitutions).

```
subsindets( Ut, `^`, z->`if`(type(op(2,z),posint) and op(1,z)=A+B,
                             foldr(`&*`,seq(op(1,z),i=1..op(2,z))),
                             z) );

subsindets( Ut, `^`, z->`if`(type(op(2,z),posint) and op(1,z)<>h,
                             foldr(`&*`,seq(op(1,z),i=1..op(2,z))),
                             z) );
```

Comment: accepted as thank's for the effort in answering.  using maple 17 now, the new physics package (which is confirming that my own [python] code works), which means I'll probably never need this.